# Given an array of arrays which contain characters, find all the arrays with at least one common character and return them as pairs

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Brute force method would be to 
1. compare each array with another array
2. If there is 1 common character; print the pair
Time: O(n3)

how would we optimize this?

Comment: All arrays which have at least one character also contained in an array other than themselves qualify?

Answer (score 3):

Lets the characters are ASCII. So the number of possible characters is 256

Example:

```
your_array = [['abc'], ['dxf'], ['xyz'], ['axd']]
```

Lets, `indices[256]` is an array of array where `indices[i]` will contain the index of those arrays who have a character with ASCII code `i`.

```
indices[97] = [0, 3] // ascii code a is 97
indices[98] = [0] // as
indices[99] = [0]
indices[100] = [1, 3]
indices[120] = [1, 2, 3]
indices[102] = [1]
indices[121] = [2]
```

Now, generate the pairs from each indices where `size(indices) > 1`

```
For indices[97]

pairs:
<['abc'], ['axd']>

......

......

......

For indices[120]

pairs:
<['dxf'], ['xyz']>
<['dxf'], ['axd']>
<['xyz'], ['axd']>
```

The space complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of array of characters.

Time complexity to build the `indices` array is `O(n)` and printing all pairs is `O(n^2)` in worst case. However, as printing all pairs(yielding output) is compulsory for the problem, that complexity is beyond consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly this can be solved the following way:

1. Count appearences of each character for each array and also build the total count for each character along the way.
2. Iterate over the character counts for the arrays and subtract it from the total, if at least one count is > 0, then the array qualifies.

Because the number of characters is constant (1 byte = 256) it is O(n * m), where n is the total number of characters and m the number of arrays.